# Problem picking image from gallery (android kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, gallery

i'm working on an app and when i want to selectan image from the gallery, the fragment from where i make the call suddenly closes. I don´t know why because it was working before.
i created another fragment, really simple to check if the error was still there and it is.

**Fragment code:**

class CargarFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var mBinding : FragmentCargarBinding
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    mBinding= FragmentCargarBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
    return mBinding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    mBinding.imgCargar.setOnClickListener {
        cargarImagenDeGaleria()
    }
}

private fun cargarImagenDeGaleria() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    intent.type = "image/*"
    startActivityForResult(intent,100)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if(requestCode==100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        mBinding.imgCargar.setImageURI(data?.data)
    }
}
```

**RUN TAB**

D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.example.cervenauta activity: com.example.cervenauta.MainActivity@be13fd4
I/chatty: uid=10349(com.example.cervenauta) identical 5 lines
D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.example.cervenauta activity: com.example.cervenauta.MainActivity@be13fd4
D/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded with stream left [23142]
E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException

Comment: When the app closed, will show an error message in the logcat section in android studio can you please paste this error message so we can understand the problem better

Comment: i have a couple of red messages, but the last one is this
2022-04-16 19:28:53.007 19985-20256/com.example.cervenauta E/DRM/DcfDecoder: decodeDrmImageIfNeeded stream caught ClassCastException
let me know ifyou want to see the others. This message also appears a like 8 times so i think its the one that is closing the fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
mBinding.imgCargar.setImageURI(Uri.parse(data?.data))
```

Comment: I just tried and same problem. That parse requested me a string so i had to add the .ToString() to the data. Like this mBinding.imgCargar.setImageURI(Uri.parse(data?.data.toString()))